# Is there way to cut one part of mesh, then apply those cuts to other parts which are identical

Tags: modeling

I forgot to cut mesh under those bars, so basically they are not connected to mesh under them. (Picture 1)

What I want to do is with knife tool cut mesh so it creates square faces(selected with orange in Blender). I did that, and want to apply it to other parts of mesh.(Picture 2)

Is there way to faster apply those changes to all other parts of mesh which are same(picture 3)I marked with blue lines where I want them(I marked just first 2 or 3, I want them all from left to right, and for every mesh behind)([image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: you could only keep one of your object and use an Array modifier to repeat it so that if you make a change on the original it will be duplicated on the others. Or use the knife (K to activate) to cut the edges and press C to cut vertically and Z to cut through, that way you can cut on the first object and it will cut edges on all the others

Comment: The one problem with that comment answer is it’s changing the definition of “object” between blender and traditional life.

Comment: yes sorry, maybe "module"

Comment: I thought about arrays since I already had and I applied it, but I had to do some more work after that so it took me amount of time and I don't know is it faster method in my case.

Comment: Duplicate the edges out and use them as a cutter for a knife project

Comment: @AllenSimpson You mean I duplicate them and then move them to merge with existing mesh? I don't seem to actually cut mesh, it looks like it just lay it on top

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/mesh/knife_project.html

Comment: You can duplicate just the edges you need, and use orthographic view to look down the axis, and cut this shape straight through the mesh.  It's a little hard to explain, I recommend you experiment with it in a new file

Comment: I'm kind of scatterbrained today, sorry my explanations suck 

Comment: No problem, it's hard to explain this things. I got this but it takes to much time to set up, and I'm lazy. Gonna see what will be :D

Comment: I got another idea but don't know how to ask. When I grab those faces which are now just lying on mesh, to extrude it all the way down on Z axis, and it cuts(intersect) by crossing any edge it meets on it's way